# Jquery div not showing with on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

What is wrong with this code ? it is not showing the 37DIV on click

```
<a href="#" id="37" class="he"> CS504 </a>
<script>
$( "#37" ).click(function() {
    $( "37DIV" ).show( "bounce", 1000 );
});
</script>
<div id="37DIV" style="display:none">       
        <a href="thread-52.html">lorem pum sum</a>          
        <a href="thread-52.html">lorem pum sum</a>      
        <a href="thread-52.html">lorem pum sum</a>      
        <a href="thread-52.html">lorem pum sum</a>      
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: you missed a `#` its `$( "#37DIV" ).show( "bounce", 1000 );`

Comment: @NandakumarV still not working

Comment: By right, you should not using id starting with digit

Comment: @user1479606 To be exact, not starting with a digit is better to conform to HTML4 (but old browsers were tolerant) but isn't needed in HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the # which tell jQuery to search by id.

Replace

```
$( "37DIV" ).
```

with

```
$("#37DIV" ).
```

You should also have your code in a ready callback.

And you must import jQuery before you use it. Put the import element in the head of your document :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> no title </title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="37" class="he"> CS504 </a>
<div id="37DIV" style="display:none">       
        <a href="thread-52.html">lorem pum sum</a>          
        <a href="thread-52.html">lorem pum sum</a>      
        <a href="thread-52.html">lorem pum sum</a>      
        <a href="thread-52.html">lorem pum sum</a>      
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#37").click(function() {
    $("#37DIV").show( "bounce", 1000 );
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that ID starting with digits aren't valid in HTML4 (but that shouldn't be a problem). Note also that jQuery 1.5 is very old. You should use a more recent version as you use a recent jQuery UI.

Comment: perfect i was missing proper html, head tags, now how to do this will toogle ()

Answer (score 1):

You need `#` before id in the selector, read more about selctors [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Change

```
 $("37DIV" ).show( "bounce", 1000 );
```

To

```
 $("#37DIV" ).show( "bounce", 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

$("#37DIV" ). instead of $( "37DIV" ). where # to specify ID

```
$( "#37" ).click(function() {
    $( "#37DIV" ).show( "bounce", 1000 );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TgZKn/5/

Comment: perfect how to do this with toogle() ?

Comment: i have added the answer for toggle in the below please check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#37" ).click(function() {
    $( "#37DIV" ).show("bounce", 1000);
});

});

</script>



</head>

<body>

<a href="#" id="37" class="he"> CS504 </a>
<div id="37DIV" style="display:none">       
        <a href="thread-52.html">lorem pum sum</a>          
        <a href="thread-52.html">lorem pum sum</a>      
        <a href="thread-52.html">lorem pum sum</a>      
        <a href="thread-52.html">lorem pum sum</a>      
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For toggle check the below

```
$( "#37" ).click(function() {
    $( "#37DIV" ).toggle("bounce" );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TgZKn/5/